# How to send mail in Katalon ( attachment Screenshot on failure )

Tags: java, reporting, katalon-studio

How can I send email with attached screenshot ( Katalon studio )

1. Capture a screenshot on failure : **OK**
2. Send email ( report with screenshot )

a/How to make from Jenkin ( Send attach email)

b/How to make keyword for Sending the email ( in Groovy )

( Note *: Katalon does not support sending email with video & picture )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Katalon Studio allows users to receive summary reports via Email after Test Suites execution. You can access this setting at Project > Settings > Email.

2 - You can execute automation test without launching Katalon Studio by using command line mode execution, you could use Jenkins to run a command line script.

[How to setup the integration with Jenkins](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/jenkins_ci_integration.html#configuration-steps)

3 - Katalon Studio supports the ability to capture test execution via video format.

After creating a test suite in Katalon Studio, select Project > Settings to open project Settings dialog box. Navigate to Report section

[Video Capturing](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/video-capturing.html)

Comment: Thank you so much LaCuadra - I hope to see you in Nexttime in StaclOverflow - Goodluck